# Older story about a sex worker on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find an older (either late 70s or early 80s) science fiction story about a woman who was a sex worker on a long distance spaceship. I remember one line where she described a typical work schedule where she said "...and that boys and girls is too much of a good thing." I read it in one of the sf digest magazines. Thanks!

Comment: @user14111 The OP is using idiomatically cromulent English (although I would add commas). You can exchange "ladies and gentlemen" for "boys and girls" to get a similar thing with a different flavor. I would guess that the character is hamming up addressing an audience as though they were a group of young students (i.e. "boys and girls") because she has accomplished, or witnessed some kind of debacle unfold from an otherwise promising start. Try reading this: "And *THAT*, boys and girls, is too much of a good thing."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Unemployment Problem](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51563) by Jor Jennings

> She was shipwrecked and out of a job, if you could call ship's whore a
> job. If only she could find her true calling...

It can be read on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v39n08_1978-12). The quote is: "And that, boys and girls, is way too much of a good thing."

Comment: +1 @user14111 Oh look, commas! ;)

Comment: Thank you, Ayshe! That has nagged at me for years.

Comment: @MichaelR since this answer appears to be correct, consider accepting it by clicking the gray checkmark.